# Django Feeds/Syndication - The functions item_title and item_description do not effect whats displayed?

Tags: django, feed, django-rss

Ive defined a a class that inherits from django.contrib.syndication.feeds.Feed

```
class Rss(Feed):
...
    def item_title(self, item):
       return "Hello"

    def item_description(self, item):
       return "Test"
```

The issue is whats returned from the methods item_title and item_description is not what is used in the feed, even when not using a template.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a recent trunk checkout, or version 1.1 or earlier? The `item_title` etc fields were only introduced since 1.1 was released.

If you're using 1.1, you should refer to the [1.1 documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/syndication/).

Comment: Ok so this works as it should, I am just not reading the right Django Docs. Thanks!!